# Showing Expected Value Does Not Exist

Tags: probability-theory

Let X be a uniform random variable on [0,1], and let $Y=\tan\left (\pi \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$. Calculate E(Y) if it exists.

After doing some research into this problem, I have discovered that Y has a Cauchy distribution (although I do not know how to prove this); therefore, E(Y) does not exist.

Also, I know that if I can show the improper integral does not absolutely converge - i.e., that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\tan\left(\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|dx$ diverges - I can show that E(Y) does not exist.

The problem is that I do not know how to evaluate this integral. Could someone please enlighten me on how to do so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Old thread, but some comments: (1) when applying the "law of the unconscious statistician" you forgot to multiply by the PDF of X. Your expectation should then be $\int_0^1 \tan(\pi (x-1/2))\,dx$. This is not in $L^1$ as the antiderivative proposed by drhab says. Hence Bill Liu's correct answer is irrelevant. (2) In a comment below you broke up the integral from 0 to 3/4 and 3/4 to 1, but it should have been from 0 to 1/2 and 1/2 to 1 and nobody corrected you. Try graphing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-\pi^{-1}\ln\cos\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ serves as primitive
of $\tan\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ on $\left(0,1\right)$

Comment: I broke up the improper integral into two pieces - one from 0 to 3/4, the other from 3/4 to 1, but I got infinity-infinity. Is this okay -  I heard that I only need to show that one of the pieces diverges?

Comment: The integrand here is non-negative. This tells you that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)dx\geq\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx$
for any interval $\left(a,b\right)$. So if found such an interval,
and it suffices $\int_{a}^{b}f\left(x\right)dx=\infty$ then can draw
the conclusion that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)dx=\infty$.
This means the integral diverges, so you are ready.

Comment: Okay, drhab, I think that's really going to help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My intuition would be, since $\tan$ is a periodic function, you can first consider a single cycle. (In this case, maybe $x\in(0,1)$.) Since you have infinite number of cycles, you can deduce that the integral diverges.

Comment: The pdf is not periodic, it's defined only on [0,1].